# Different results for same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I connected to two different sql server which both of them on different server and i am running same query . one of the server returns me results with '.' other returns with ',' like 
6492420,66 and 6492420.66 . Both of the server has same regional settings (English- united states) .
How can i solve this problem . I am trying to have both result with "."

Comment: In Oracle you can set the locale of a connection. Other systems might offer the same. Or read numbers as numbers but not as strings.

Comment: In `Database Properties > Options`, what is the collation for each of the databases?

Comment: Describe what you mean by 'returns'...are you looking in Management Studio or in some kind of client or web page? And are you looking at results from the same computer or from different computers?

Comment: Hi, i am using Management studio and same computers

Answer (score 0):

It's login specific.

Security->Logins->(your login)->General->Default Language

or

`ALTER LOGIN [your_login] WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]`

Comment: it returns same different results from same login

Comment: Yes, but logins are server specific...so the `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE` could be different for the same login on different servers...